# Need a word-pair along the lines of simulacra

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a pair of words to respectively represent a “real” thing and for  multiple representations of that “real” thing.

*Simulacra* is close, but I’m not aware of any term for the object that is being mimicked, and I’m not sure its usage is common enough for people to know the term.

I like *replicant* (the fake people in *Bladerunner*), but there are some issues using it.  *Silhouette* feels close, but not quite there.

The hologram watch from *Total Recall* comes to mind in describing what I’m looking for.  The idea is that there is the real object, but you can interact with the copies just like the original such that it doesn’t matter that they aren’t the original.

Sorry, the words I’m looking for would work well in describing what I’m looking for!

---

### Edit

I’m working on a software library for [interprocess communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), and am trying to come up with a few terms that convey the intent.  The idea is that you create an object in your process that behaves the expected way, and it doesn't matter whether the “real” object exists in another process. If the object is in another process, the library handles all of the communication to keep things synchronized with that (real) object so your version behaves exactly the same way.

Proxy and RPC (*remote procedure call*) focus on the information transport.  I’m looking to convey the intent instead of the implementation.  I do need terms for each, so I can describe the implementation to people.

---

### Edit2

Updated to clarify question.  I'm not sure what the line is between describing a conceptual behavior in computer programming vs. naming of a class.  The suggestions have been very helpful for helping me figure out how to describe what I'm working on, so it is unfortunate that my question has been put on hold as off-topic.

Comment: Can you give us some context? It could help us narrow things down if we knew what you were describing.

Comment: Is this along the lines of [pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29) in computer programming? Multiple references to the "original", each reference can manipulate the original. This may help guide the discussion, if I interact with one of these copies and cause it to be altered (say I paint it red), will all the other copies and the original exhibit that same modification?

Comment: @Ansssssss - Yes, it is along these lines.  Modifications are propagated to all instances.

Comment: Given the context, I think [proxy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Proxy) works best. Note that none of the definitions focus on information transport, and even in a software context "proxy" doesn't make me think of information transport.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about names for use in a software context.

Comment: The grammatical terms are _antecedent_ (for the original) and _anaphor_ for anything like a pronoun or something else that refers to the antecedent. It's a decent match here, because "antecedent" means "coming before", and, while grammatical antecedents don't always precede their anaphors in a sentence, originals **always** precede their copies in time. Plus, there are various categories of anaphors -- and a classic Greek plural _anaphora_ to cover the whole subject of coreference, in case you need to falute highly -- and you can tailor the categories to suit your needs.

Comment: *Changeling*, *golem*, *mock* (as a noun), *virtual*

Comment: You're implementing the same thing as [Microsoft's .NET Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973857.aspx), [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), or [Java RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Remote_Method_Invocation) - their names will not only mean what you want, they'll also help developers familiar with those technologies understand what you are doing.  .NET and Java use some similar names, so I'd start there.

Answer (score 3):

- The first word I thought of when I read your question was ***proxy***,
  but I guess you’re saying that you don’t like it.
- I believe that, for better or worse, ***surrogate*** is similar to ***proxy***.
- Your mention of a hologram suggests ***virtual object***,
  which is naturally paired with ***real object***.
- I know somebody else mentioned it, but I believe that ***replica*** is good. 
  For example, Lotus Notes allows an organization to have multiple copies of a database,
  distributed around the world, if appropriate. 
  These copies are called *replicas*. 
  Users interact with the nearest replica, and so get decent response time. 
  Changes are *replicated* (i.e., propagated) to the other sites.
- ***Mirror*** is similar. 
  Compare to its usage for replicated web sites for downloading files; e.g., software.
- You mentioned ***silhouette***. 
  How about ***shadow***?
- More generic: ***primary*** vs. ***secondary***,
  and, at the risk of being politically incorrect, ***master*** vs. ***slave***.

Comment: My issue with proxy is that it is used a lot, usually to mean something that modifies something else.  You put a proxy around something to enforce a consistent interface around several objects that have different interfaces.  My intent is to have the same "object", so you can't tell.  I thought of shadow as well, but that, I think, has sinister connotations.

Comment: These are all great suggestions. It's a shame the question was closed, but my +1 goes to you, as (specifically in a software context but also grammatically/in a lexical context) words like *surrogate*, *shadow*, and *mirror* are all terms that work and are in common usage for OP's purpose to accomplish OP's intended usage.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.  For example, in the world of industrial design we have:

*production* v.s. *mock-up*

in the world of system engineering we have:

*implementation* v.s. *simulation*

What is your context??

Answer (score 2):

For the original, consider

> - prototype
> - paradigm
> - archetype
> - epitome

For the simulacrum, perhaps

> - copy
> - facsimile
> - replica
> - duplicate
> - clone
> - autotype (images only)
> - reproduction
> - repro (slangy)
> - knockoff (a bit derogatory)

Comment: Thanks for all of these suggestions!  Need to look into some of these after work.

Comment: archetype/facsimile seems like a pair that fits your intended usage quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Since OP specifically says *it doesn't matter that they aren't the original*, I suggest they're all...

> [***fungibles***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fungible) (as a plural noun; they could be adjectivally referred to as *fungible*)
>   *Something that is exchangeable or substitutable. Often used in the plural.*

This was originally very much a legal term (if you lend someone a dollar bill, you don't necessarily expect to be repaid with *the same bill*, since all dollar bills are fungible/interchangeable). But in the modern age with so many sophisticated copying mechanisms (and [theories of reality](http://mag.digitalpc.co.uk/Olive/ODE/physicsworld/LandingPage/LandingPage.aspx?href=UEhZU1dvZGUvMjAxMS8wNS8wMQ..&pageno=MzY.&entity=QXIwMzYwMA..&view=ZW50aXR5)), the word is becoming more widely used in a range of contexts.

Comment: The definition is really close.  But for a name for my library, "fungibles" just doesn't sound good.  +1 anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Brett: Ah well. But I'm afraid by that reasoning (and more particularly, following your recent edit) the question is Off Topic anyway. ELU doesn't do "names for use in software contexts".

Answer (score 2):

You actually used the word in your question.  It's called a "representation", and that is exactly the word and the computer-science concept that used in REST, which stands for "REpresentational State Transfer".

For example, let's say we have a "profile".  One "representation" of this profile is a bunch of HTML with embedded images that is viewable through a web browser, as a UI component.  People think of this as "the profile", but in "reality" the profile is a row in a database table, and the HTML page is a representation of that profile.  If a person updates their profile, then requests the HTML, the representation will be updated to match the underlying data.  The programming concept of a "representation" already has the concept of synchronizing built in.  Gotta represent, yo.

A different representation is a string of JSON, returned by an API.  It contains the same data, because it is a "representation" of the "actual thing".

So the terminology you're looking for could be and "object" and its "representations".

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking at ***facade*** or ***facet***. The facade is all your object sees.

I'm having difficulty finding a pair for it though. On the inside you could consider ***implementation***, often abbreviated `Impl`, or ***realization***. On the other side of the implementation coin, though, usually you would use ***interface*** instead of facade. This is especially true in what I'll call "languages that look and feel surprisingly similar to Java" (Java, C#, D, plenty of others.)

This just goes to show you, there's only [two hard things in computer science](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html): cache invalidation and naming things. (and off by one errors...)

Comment: LOL.  Yes, naming things is hard!  Wish I could give  a 2nd +1 for that.

Comment: The counterpart to ***facet*** might be ***core***.

Answer (score 1):

You could pair *simulacra* with *referent* in line with Jean Baudrillard's concept of total simulation and the absence of the Real. See the Wikipedia article on [Jean Baudrillard’s Simulacra and Simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacra_and_Simulation) for more about this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised this hasn’t been mentioned yet, but:

> [**dop·pel·gäng·er**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/doppelganger)  *noun* 
>   a ghostly double or counterpart of a living person.

You mention a hologram, which could be considered ghostly in appearance. In common usage, I’ve heard the word to most commonly mean a duplicate or replication intended to appear identical to the original, even to the point of replacing the original. It can be similar in connotation to a *forgery*, except when embodied as a person or living thing, the thing itself is also the *forger*.

But, this doesn’t hold up in your added context of a software object. Also, it’s quite cumbersome in a programming-variable or repeated-typing context, in my opinion. But if you need to expose the real and fake objects through a user interface, I think it could work well.

The literal translation of the word from German is *double-goer* or *double-walker* which works quite well for a software term, reality-reflecting term, or a user-interface term.

Comment: Good one.  I wondering "why didn't I think of that", BTW!

Answer (score 1):

You might call it 'bilocation' or even 'polylocation' to show that the object is in multiple places at the same time, and call the copies 'projections' and the originals 'original'. 
Something along the lines of 'ubiquitous' or 'omnipresent' could work for the library name, but I like the idea of an 'original object' 'bilocating' through 'projections' :)

Answer (score 1):

Already in use in RPC (at least in Java) - **'Stub'** - which is the class that gets 'exposed' but it's not the 'real' thing.

From software testing (and other things), **'Dummy'** as in 'Dummy Objects' which are the ones 'filling in' for the real ones.

**'Pseudo'**, typically used a prefix but it can be used on it's own, meaning false or fake, as in pseudo-science (not 'really' science) or an amoeba has a pseudopod (false appendage).

Comment: One of my favorite words (in the “guilty pleasures” category) is [***ersatz***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ersatz?s=t). dictionary.com defines it as an adjective as “serving as a substitute; synthetic; artificial,” or as a noun as “an artificial substance or article used to replace something natural or genuine; a substitute.” (So there are two possible counterparts: *natural* and *genuine*, and from *artificial* we get *real*.) I’ve always thought of *ersatz* as an adjective, with a meaning somewhere between *pseudo* and *virtual*; again, *real* works.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider ***[lifelike experience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifelike_experience)***. It is also easy to understand.

> Lifelike is an adjective that relates to anything that simulates real life, in accordance with its laws. Its goal is to immerse individuals into what is called a lifelike experience. It gets as close as possible to real life behavior, appearance, senses, etc. therefore enabling its subject to experience what is happening as if it were real. In other words, **simulating reality with its physical laws** is the objective of lifelike experience.

Answer (score 0):

I second Luke G's suggestion of "object"/"representation", but here are a few other word-pairs that might be useable:

- "Vehicle"/"Tenor".  (This comes from the two parts of a [metaphor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor).)
- "Ideal"/"Object".  (In the sense of Platonic ideal.)
- "Prototype"/"Instance"

Hope these help.